# how to get number of documents term appear in, in elasticsearch rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch

if I have many documents and want to know " how many documents the term 'rails'  appear in "
is there a way to get this information from elasticsearch " tire gem " from the index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facets to make something like SQL 'group-by' aggregate function, as described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html) in elasticsearch documentation.
A sample code would look like:

```
index_name = "documents" # name of your index
search_word = 'rails' # word searching for
field_name = 'document_text' # field to search in
search = Tire.search index_name do
  query do
    string "#{field_name}:#{search_word}"
  end
  facet 'ids-facets', :global => false do
    terms :id
  end
end
document_ids = search.results.facets['ids-facets']['terms']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to reindex the model ?